# Strange behaviour with symfony 4 session handler on docker swarm

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I'm experiencing something i've never come across before when i've moved a symfony application to a docker swarm; weirdly it only starts to happen after maybe 12 hours of running fine.

When making api calls to the symfony domain on the app from the angular frontend, symfony is randomly now responding with:

```
Warning: ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time
```

Looking at the trace it's picking it up from NativeFileSessionHandler.php:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', $savePath);        
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
```

Anyone have any idea why this is randomly happening? I am running everything on docker swarm with an nginx web server and php-fpm container, and as i say it all works perfectly fine for 12 hours or so, the session files are being created without a problem as well.

If i now re-deploy the swarm the error goes away. There is no error with nginx here, it's a 200 response.

Comment: search for a PHP typo or some refuse character at the start of some files

Comment: Wouldn't that make it happen all the time? Not just after 12 hours